# Change Notification in Microsoft Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating a subscription to a list in Microsoft SharePoint and everything works well. Anytime  make a change in the list I'm subscribed to, I get a notification.

But I would like to be able to see which item was changed instead of just seeing that there was a change in the list. For example, I made a subscription to a list and changed some metadata in one of the items that were in that list. Microsoft sent me this as the notification: [Notification from change in SharePoint list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSCgU.png). The most useful information in this message is the resource, but that is just the path the list that I am subscribed to.

The only way that I have found so that I can find what item was changed is if I make a GET request on Microsoft Graph Explorer that says: [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{domain](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/%7Bdomain) name}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{SiteName}:/lists/{listID}/activities

This gives me all the recent events that happened in the list, [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caB3q.png). It includes the notification id, the user who made the change, and the time that it happened. This information is nice to have, but it doesn't directly lead me to finding out which item was changed.

I had an idea that I could look at the time that a notification happened at (given by the GET request that shows recent activities in the list), and then try to match that with the the lastModifiedDateTime of one of the items in my list. However, I tried this a few times and found that the time that a notification occurred did not always completely match the lastModifiedDateTime of the item that I changed.

Has anyone found a better way to do this? I would ideally like to be able to find the ID of the item that changed, but anything that is more reliable than the modification time would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do this. The ideal solution would be to have the [resource data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data) in the change notification. Because this is currently not supported, I suggest you create a feature request [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for it so that it may be implemented in future.